# 3 Column Div how to display them inline when browser resize?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs but the 3rd div comes down when i resize the browser.

[image]

How can i still display them inline when browser resize?

I can do it by changing the width of my `container`

but i want it to be 100%

This is my Code:

```css
.box{
    float :left; 
    width: 250px;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    min-height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-right: 26px;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <br style="clear: left;">
</div>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/r2bp3gfe/4), in short, Learn [**display: flex**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [**CSS3 flexible box layout**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) so that the elements do not wrap to next line and resize accordingly. The default values of `flex-direction` is `row` and `flex-wrap` is `nowrap`. So you need not set the values here.

```css
.box {
  width: 250px;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  min-height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 26px;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex; /* Added */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <br style="clear: left;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this -

```css
.box{float:left;
    max-width: 250px;
    min-width: 20%;
    /*max-width: 250px;*/
    background: #f6f6f6;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    min-height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-right: 26px;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <br style="clear: left;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying `.box {width: 250px}` make it in percentage, remove margin, add `box-sizing` for padding issue:

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  /* Instead of old 250px; */
  background: #f6f6f6;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  min-height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* To include padding to width */
  /*margin-right: 26px; Can't use margin for responsive gaps*/
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <br style="clear: left;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added an inner div

```css
bodY{
margin: 0;
}
.box{
float :left; 
width: 250px;
background: #f6f6f6;
border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
min-height: 150px;
position: relative;
padding: 20px;
margin-right: 26px;
}
.box:nth-child(3){
margin-right: 0;
}
.container{
overflow-x: hidden;
width: 100%;
}
.inner{
margin-right: -400px;
width: 928px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="inner">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <br style="clear: left;">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easy if you try bootstrap.

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
   //first div contents
 </div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
  //second div contents
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
  // third div contents
</div>
```

Note you should include required bootstrap files to use this classes